# Disabling jQuery-ui draggable/droppable for mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, responsive-design

So my website has a droppable/draggable implemented on it and it's also responsive. When I'm visiting the website on my phone, I'm unable to scroll over the stuff that are draggable.

Is there anyway to disable it for mobile users?

Comment: jQuery UI does not support touch events, so it won't work i mobile devices by default. Have you included touch punch..?

Answer (score 1):

1. Just write function, that detect mobile by user agent or by device width.

**By user agent**

```
function detectmob() { 
 if( navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i)
 || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)
 ){
    return true;
  }
 else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**By device width**

```
function detectmob() {
   if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
     return true;
   } else {
     return false;
   }
}
```

2. Than remove class .dragable from each elemnt causing problem when scrolling on the smartphone.

```
$("element").removeClass(".dragable");
```